# How can I use an object in a different class?

Tags: c#

I've been messing around in C# a little bit and I've stumbled into a problem for which I haven't managed to find an answer. I created two objects in main from another .cs file and I would like to assign a value for a variable associated with the object in another class. After about an hour of looking, I have no idea how to do it. Here is my code (I know it's not perfect; I'm just starting to learn):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Converse
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Subject subject1 = new Subject();
        Subject subject2 = new Subject();

        Generate.generation();

    }
}
}
```

Then

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Converse
{
public class Subject
{
    public int persuasion;

    public Subject()
    {
        persuasion = 0;
    }
}
}
```

And on this last one, lines 17 and 19 are the problem:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Converse
{
public static class Generate
{
   public static void generation()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Control over Subject  1's personality? ");
       Console.WriteLine("1) None");
       Console.WriteLine("2) Minimal");
       Console.WriteLine("3) Considerable");

       subject1.persuasion = Console.ReadKey();

       switch (subject1.persuasion)
       {
           case 1:
               break;

           case 2:
               GenerationFunctions.lightGen();
               break;

           case 3:
               GenerationFunctions.heavyGen();
               break;
           default:
               break;
       }


       Console.ReadKey();
   }
}
```

}

Can anybody tell me how to code this properly?

Thanks

Comment: I don't even know how to respond to this without sounding like a jerk... Have you had any programming classes?

Comment: @Nick: I was going to say the same thing, but instead I just ate it and wrote an answer pointing out the obvious.

Comment: @caesay I don't even know how obvious that is though without knowing what else he plans to do. Maybe the solution is to make subject1 and subject2 private variables in the Generate class, or maybe your answer is correct to just pass a parameter to generation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code. You need to pass a reference to your subject to the generation void.

```
public static void generation(Subject subject)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Control over Subject  1's personality? ");
   Console.WriteLine("1) None");
   Console.WriteLine("2) Minimal");
   Console.WriteLine("3) Considerable");

   subject.persuasion = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadKey());

   switch (subject.persuasion)
   {
       case 1:
           break;

       case 2:
           GenerationFunctions.lightGen();
           break;

       case 3:
           GenerationFunctions.heavyGen();
           break;
       default:
           break;
   }
}
```

then to call:

```
Subject subject1 = new Subject();

Generate.generation(subject1);
```